# SQL Row Counter

Tags: sql-server

I need to return a value based on the number of matching fields.

Current Output

```
Job   |  Image
A1234 |  FileA
A1234 |  FileB
A1235 |  FileA
A1236 |  FileA
A1236 |  FileB
A1236 |  FileC
```

Desired Output

```
Job   |  Image  | Order
A1234 |  FileA  |  1
A1234 |  FileB  |  2
A1235 |  FileA  |  1
A1236 |  FileA  |  1
A1236 |  FileB  |  2
A1236 |  FileC  |  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Job
      ,Image
      ,Order = Row_Number() over (Partition By Job Order By Image)
 From YourTable
```